# oracle concurrent insert and update

Tags: oracle, concurrency, transactions

I'm writing a program which stores service invocations. My tables:

```
messages(id, content)
invocations(correlation_id, request_id, response_id).
```

The program receives data on more thread and does in transaction:

```
insert content into messages
set request or response id  in invocations
if update returned 0 then insert invocations
```

Sometimes the transaction is rolled back becase of primery key violation.

```
tr1 insert request into messages
tr2 insert respone into messages
tr1 try to update invocations but return 0
tr2 try to update invocations but return 0
tr1 insert into invocations
tr2 insert into invocations but this will fail
tr1 commit
tr2 rollback becouse of PK violation
```

I've tried to change the isolation level to serializable and tried to use merge instead of update and isnert, but neither one resolved the problem.

How can I store and update invocations in correct way?

Comment: If you have two transactions that both want to insert the same row into invocations with the same PK, then there is a logic problem going on here with your app with multiple writers.  Have you considered using Advanced Queuing (AQ) to write your changes to a queue, then have a handler read from the queue and decide on the logic to take?

Comment: My application read the data from a Websphere MQ then insert it into database. If request and response data for the same invocation read simultaneously then there is the concurrency problem. If I've read the queue with only one thread there would be no problem. I think that there is some feautre in oracle to resolve but I don't know how.